# Temporary disable button on ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

How can i enable or disable the paragraph button of CKEditor on selection of an image. I did not want to remove it completely.
am currently using ckeditor version 4.4

Comment: "paragraph button", which is...? Text direction button?

Comment: sorry ijust want to avoid the justifyLeft,justifyRight,justifyCenter buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`editor.getCommand()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getCommand) + [`CKEDITOR.command` API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.command) (`enable` and `disable`):

```
editor.getCommand( 'justifyleft' ).disable();
editor.getCommand( 'justifyleft' ).enable();
```

For example:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'selectionChange', function( evt ) {
    var jLeftCommand = this.getCommand( 'justifyleft' ),
        jRightCommand = this.getCommand( 'justifyright' );

    if ( evt.data.path.lastElement.is( 'img' ) ) { 
        jLeftCommand.disable();
        jRightCommand.disable();
    } else {
        jLeftCommand.enable();
        jRightCommand.enable();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much Oleq, the selection change is working fine, but when I select, it's not identifying whether it's an image or not. 

When I alert evt.data.path.lastElement.toSource(), I'm getting the following:

On clicking image, it shows:

({$:{'data-cke-expando':69}, getName:(function (){return a})})

and on clicking text, it shows:

({$:{}, getName:(function (){return a})})

Could you tell me why it's showing like this please? It's not identifying whether it's an image or not.

Thank you.

Comment: On some further check, I got a way to identify whether it's an image or not. I've used it like  if ( CKEDITOR.instances.editorid.getSelection().getType() == 3 ) { //it is an image } else { //not image }. Could you confirm this whether it's an alternative for if ( evt.data.path.lastElement.is( 'img' ) ) ? Thank you very much.